# HOW TO use SQL SUM WITH SPECIFIC CONDITION

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

i have 3 tables as per below

**Table Referral**

| id | name | ref_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ANDY | AN123 |
| 2 | BEN | BE34 |
| 3 | CHARLES | CH44 |
| 4 | DANNY | DA66 |

**Table Application**

| app_id | ref_code | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APP1 | AN123 | 2 |
| APP2 | AN123 | 2 |
| APP3 | CH44 | 3 |
| APP4 | DA66 | 3 |
| APP5 | DA66 | 1 |
| APP6 | CH44 | 1 |

**Table FINANCING**

| app_id | AMOUNT |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APP1 | 1000 |  |
| APP2 | 1500 |  |
| APP3 | 2000 |  |
| APP4 | 3000 |  |
| APP5 | 4000 |  |
| APP6 | 1000 |  |

I want to show referral summary like below table, i want to show referral when they have applciation with status where in (1,2). approve case is when status = 2

here is my sql

```
SELECT
  referral.name,COUNT(application.ref_code) as total ,SUM(financing.amount) as total financing,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN application.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as TOTAL CASE APPROVE
  
FROM referral
  JOIN application
  ON application.ref_code= referral.ref_code
  JOIN financing
  ON application.app_id= financing.app_id
 
    where  application.status IN ('1','2')
  GROUP BY referral.name
```

from sql above, i can show table as below

| NAME | TOTAL FINANCING | TOTAL ALL CASE | TOTAL CASE approved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANDY | 2500 | 2 | 2 |
| CHARLES | 2000 | 1 | 0 |
| DANNY | 3000 | 1 | 0 |

i have no idea how to show the last column (total financing amount for approved case only, where status=2).

**here is table that i want to show**

| NAME | TOTAL FINANCING | TOTAL CASE | TOTAL CASE APPROVED | FINANCING approved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANDY | 2500 | 2 | 2 | 2500 |
| CHARLES | 2000 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| DANNY | 3000 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

thank u in advance

Comment: please always tag the database system you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can sum "financing.amount" the same way you did with "TOTAL CASE APPPROVE"

```
SUM(
    CASE WHEN application.status=2 THEN
    financing.amount
    ELSE 0 END
)
as TOTAL financing amount CASE APPROVE
```